# Fedora 18 detecting non-existent monitor

Tags: fedora, x11, monitors

I have an HP Envy dv7 with a dual boot setup of Win 8 and Fedora 18. On 07/22/2013 I updated all packages in Fedora 18 that had updates available.

After a reboot, Fedora is now detecting that a second monitor is connected on the vga-2 port (according to `xrandr`) but I don't have a second monitor. Is there a way to prevent it from detecting this monitor?

Edit:

Thanks for the suggestion below [@slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84350/7453) however that just gave me a blank screen. While working on that solution I realized that there is a new grub menu entry. I compared it to the old menu entry and the only difference is the kernel version. If I log in with the old version the problem isn't there but if I use the new version it is.

If I run xrandr with the old kernel I get the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1600x900       60.0*+   40.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

However if I run it under the new kernel I get:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1600x900       60.0*+   40.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
  1024x768 (0x63)   65.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x64)   40.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x65)   36.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
```

Not sure what's causing this but since I can still use the old kernel, I'll just do that and see if Fedora pushes out an update that fixes it. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Please provide output from `xrandr`. Edit your question and add it there please.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this potential workaround. Add the following to your grub2 boot loader kernel parameters. Edit the file, `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`:

```
linux /vmlinuz-… video=LVDS-1:d
```

Also you can use `xrandr` to enable/disable the different devices you have connected manually.

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 303mm x 190mm
   1440x900       60.0*+   50.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

To turn off LVDS1:

```
$ xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
```

I'd also try this:

```
$ xrandr --auto
```

It should disable any enabled outputs that are disconnected, i.e. your mysterious 2nd monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I was also seeing an extra monitor while taking screenshots or screencasting. xrandr method explained above didn't worked for me. I Used the GUI approach.Went to Display Settings -> chose the second monitor and turned it off. The monitor is still shown in the Display Manager but it doesn't seem to affect screencasting etc.[image: Turning off the Unknown display]